# How to implement "WHERE" condition in Couchbase-lite in Android

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I want to find all the documents in which a particular key has a same given value. In SQL, this can be implemented using WHERE clause. In Mongo, I can use find(). But I'm not sure how to implement this in Couchbase-lite in Android. It would be great if someone can help to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

Code for creating and initializing views:

```
com.couchbase.lite.View dateTimeView = database.getView("dateTimeView");
dateTimeView.setMap(new Mapper() {
    @Override
    public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
        String dateTime = (String) document.get(QuickstartPreferences.DATE_TIME); // String for Key
        emitter.emit(dateTime, null);        
    }
}, "1");
```

Code for querying the aforementioned view:

```
Query query = database.getView("dateTimeView").createQuery();
query.setLimit(100);
query.setStartKey(date_time); //to retreive records for a given date_time value
query.setEndKey(date_time); 
QueryEnumerator result = null;
try {
    result = query.run();    
    for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
        QueryRow row = it.next();
        <String, Object> map = row.getDocument().getProperties();
        String employeeName = map.get(QuickstartPreferences.EMPLOYEE_NAME).toString(); // String for Key
        if(employeeName.equalsIgnoreCase(employee_name)) {
            // other logic
        }
    }
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The important point in here is when you setMap for the view the values of querying field have to be set as the `Key` (not as the `Value`). The `value` could be `null`. Then, you can easily use `setStartKey` & `setEndKey` functions.

Answer (score 1):

CouchbaseLite is based on concept of **Map/Reduce**. You have to define a ***View*** on your database and then set its **Map** function which will run over every single document in the database and create an index for your desired query. For example:

```
View userView= database.getView("User");
userView.setMap(new Mapper() {
    @Override
    public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
        // Your Logic here
        String Id = document.get("Id").toString();
        if (Id != null && Id.contains("John")) {
            emitter.emit(Id, document);
        }
    }
}, "1");
Query query = userView.createQuery();
QueryEnumerator result = query.run();
for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
    QueryRow row = it.next();
    Log.e("myDocument", row.getDocument().toString())
}
```

Unfortunately CouchbaseLite does not support N1QL yet but I have read that its on their future road-map.

Comment: Thanks Mohsin for your answer. I wanted to use `setStartKey` & `setEndKey` functions for querying data that fulfil the condition in order to make it more generic. Below is how I did it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Lite doesn't use a query language; it uses map/reduce. It sounds as though you haven't encountered that before. We have documentation on [how map/reduce views work](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html) and how to query them.

Comment: Thanks Jens for your answer. I had seen this documentation earlier. But it was not clear how to use `setStartKey` & `setEndKey` functions to query the records that fit into the condition. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to understand with map reduce is that neither map nor reduce is the right place to write where clause.

The map function will only be called if View does not exist. Therefore, it will be called when data changes because of data sync or user operations. Comparing some document property with user passed value in map function is fundamentally wrong.

The correct way would be to use map as a select clause with only value independent filtering (if any). After that, we can perform value based checking when we receive query object from the View.